# SIGEP dos Correios problemas com solicitaEtiquetas()

Tags: api, web-service

Amigos,

Estou com um problema quando solicito a criação de etiquetas no SIGEP-WEB. Estou usando o php-sigep.

Rodando o exemplo do php-sigep tudo OK. Nesse caso o exemplo envia o número da etiqueta já. Na minha aplicação preciso solicitar esse número aos correios.

No arquivo "exemplos/helper-criar-pre-lista.php" incluo a linha:

```
$params = new \PhpSigep\Model\SolicitaEtiquetas();
$params->setQtdEtiquetas(1);
$params->setServicoDePostagem(\PhpSigep\Model\ServicoDePostagem::SERVICE_PAC_41068);
$params->setAccessData(new \PhpSigep\Model\AccessDataHomologacao());

$etiqueta = \PhpSigep\Services\SoapClient\Real::solicitaEtiquetas($params);
```

Como resposta a essa solicitação tenho:

PhpSigep\Services\Result Object
(
    [isSoapFault:protected] => 1
    [errorCode:protected] => 0
    [errorMsg:protected] => Resposta do Correios: Não foi possível obter as etiquetas solicitadas.
    [result:protected] => 
    [soapFault:protected] => 
    [_failIfAtributeNotExiste:protected] => 1
)

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: @Szag-Ot pode me dar uma luz? :)

Comment: @Stavarengo podem me dar uma luz? :)

Answer (score 1):

**Resposta curta**

Vc não pode gerar etiquetas em ambiente de homologação. Vc precisa entrar em contatos com os Correios para conseguir seus dados de acesso ao ambiente correto (caso vc ainda não tenha).

**Resposta longa**

@leandro-carneiro, nesse mesmo arquivo (bem próximo de onde vc adicionou essas novas linhas) existe este comentário que colei abaixo.

```
// Estamos criando uma etique falsa, mas em um ambiente real você deve usar o
// método {@link \PhpSigep\Services\SoapClient\Real::solicitaEtiquetas() }
// para gerar o número das etiquetas
$etiqueta = new \PhpSigep\Model\Etiqueta();
$etiqueta->setEtiquetaSemDv('PD73958096BR');
```

Alem disto, eu reparei que o código que vc inseriu no arquivo está tentando gerar etiquetas usando o ambiente de homologação dos Correios. A linha de código que indica isso é esta: `$params->setAccessData(new \PhpSigep\Model\AccessDataHomologacao());`

A resposta que vc está recebendo não é gerada dentro da library. Esta mensagem `Resposta do Correios: Não foi possível obter as etiquetas solicitadas.` significa que é o próprio WebService do Correios que está retornando a mensagem `Não foi possível obter as etiquetas solicitadas.`.

Por todos estes motivos, acredito que o seu problema seja o fato de estar usando o ambiente de homologação (que não permite gerar etiquetas).

Comment: Obrigado @Stavarengo!
Apesar de usar a linha que referencia o arquivo de homologação, os dados eram de produção. Porém a senha que o cliente me enviou estava errada. Com a senha certa rodou perfeito!

Comment: @LeandroCarneiro , desculpe estar ressuscitando este tópico, mas me deparei neste problema hoje tentando realizar a integração para um cliente, porem o telefone que tenho dos correios o pessoal não sabe informar nada sobre Ambiente de produção ou de Homologação.
Por acaso poderiam me informar em que telefone falo com eles , o que tenho e o 03000888